# What is the easiest way to change the default font in Reactstrap?

Tags: reactjs, sass, bootstrap-4, reactstrap

I'm styling a MERN project and I'd like to change the default font that Reactstrap (https://reactstrap.github.io/) uses for my React frontend.  I've found some answers for changing the default Bootstrap 4 fonts, but I'm not sure how (or if) to apply those to Reactstrap -- any help or leads much appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can import a css file in the entry file of the application. The css file can contain @import tags to load your custom font. Then you can set the `font-family` in the `body` selector tag.

```
# In entry file
import '/assets/css/mycssfile.css';


# In mycssfiles.css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');

body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```